# Bash Script: count unique lines in file

Tags: bash

## Situation:

I have a large file (millions of lines) containing IP addresses and ports from a several hour network capture, one ip/port per line.  Lines are of this format:

```
ip.ad.dre.ss[:port]
```

## Desired result:

There is an entry for each packet I received while logging, so there are a lot of duplicate addresses.  I'd like to be able to run this through a shell script of some sort which will be able to reduce it to lines of the format

```
ip.ad.dre.ss[:port] count
```

where `count` is the number of occurrences of that specific address (and port).  No special work has to be done, treat different ports as different addresses.

So far, I'm using this command to scrape all of the ip addresses from the log file:

```
grep -o -E [0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)? ip_traffic-1.log > ips.txt
```

From that, I can use a fairly simple regex to scrape out all of the ip addresses that were sent by my address (which I don't care about)

I can then use the following to extract the unique entries:

```
sort -u ips.txt > intermediate.txt
```

I don't know how I can aggregate the line counts somehow with sort.

Answer (score 392, accepted):

You can use the `uniq` command to get counts of sorted repeated lines:

```
sort ips.txt | uniq -c
```

To get the most frequent results at top (thanks to Peter Jaric):

```
sort ips.txt | uniq -c | sort -bgr
```

Comment: I like how `-bgr` coincidentally looks like a mnemonic for `bigger`, which is what we want at the top.

Comment: As a small function for your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` file:
`function countuniquelines () { sort "$1" | uniq -c | sort -bgr; }`. Call by `countuniquelines myfile.txt`.

Comment: Not sure why not `sort -nr`.

Answer (score 22):

To *count* the total number of unique lines (i.e. not considering duplicate lines) we can use `uniq` or Awk with `wc`:

```
sort ips.txt | uniq | wc -l
awk '!seen[$0]++' ips.txt | wc -l
```

Awk's arrays are associative so it may run a little faster than sorting.

Generating text file:

```
$  for i in {1..100000}; do echo $RANDOM; done > random.txt
$ time sort random.txt | uniq | wc -l
31175

real    0m1.193s
user    0m0.701s
sys     0m0.388s

$ time awk '!seen[$0]++' random.txt | wc -l
31175

real    0m0.675s
user    0m0.108s
sys     0m0.171s
```

Comment: Interesting. Might make an appreciable difference for huge datasets

Answer (score 8):

This is the fastest way to get the count of the repeated lines and have them nicely printed sored by the least frequent to the most frequent:

```
awk '{!seen[$0]++}END{for (i in seen) print seen[i], i}' ips.txt | sort -n
```

If you don't care about performance and you want something easier to remember, then simply run:

```
sort ips.txt | uniq -c | sort -n
```

PS:

*sort -n* parse the field as a number, that is correct since we're sorting using the counts.

Comment: The `!` in `{!seen[$0]++}` is redundant here, as we only do the printing at the `END`.

Comment: In my example (3.7GB file with 187M lines and few repeats) using sort both times ended up being faster.  The difference may be that I set the locale to C (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do for example).  `LC_ALL=C sort ips.txt | LC_ALL=C uniq -c | LC_ALL=C sort -bgr > ips.out`