# Count a word in a line only once while for looping

Tags: bash, command-line, data-manipulation

I really need help for a specific approach.

I have a list like this;

```
promoter-TSS (NM_004753)
intron (NM_001013630, intron 2 of 3)
Intergenic  
intron (NM_001135610, intron 6 of 7)
Intergenic  
Intergenic  
Intergenic  
intron (NM_201628, intron 1 of 14)
```

and for example intron is counting more than once in a line.
I want to count every word in a single line only once.

For the above list, the output should be ;

```
promoter count : 1
intron count : 3 #not 6
Intergenic count : 5
```

Generally, I manipulate these kind of txt files in command line.
I need to run this for a big set so that I really need help! Thank you so so much

Comment: `Intergeneric` should be 4 not 5 yes?

Comment: Any how, search here S.O. there are some duplicates already, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984414/bash-script-count-unique-lines-in-file

Comment: EXACTLY, my bad

Comment: Or this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333498/shell-script-to-get-hosts-and-the-total-number-of-requests-per-host-from-log-fil

Comment: You want the counts of the first column where space or - is the column delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```sh
$ awk -F'[ \t]+|-' '
    { counts[$1]++ }
    END { for (c in counts) printf "%s count : %d\n", c, counts[c] }' input.txt
Intergenic count : 4
intron count : 3
promoter count : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When the first word is followed by `-` or a space, you can count the first words with

```
sed 's/[ -].*//' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- fields are delimited by non-alphanumerics (ie, `^[:alnum:]`)
- using case insensitive comparisons
- in OP's expected output `intergeneric` count should be 4
- ignore blank lines

Sample data:

```
$ cat list.dat
promoter-TSS (NM_004753)
intron (NM_001013630, intron 2 of 3)
Intergenic
intron (NM_001135610, intron 6 of 7)
Intergenic
Intergenic
Intergenic
Intron (NM_201628, intron 1 of 14)              # case change for first character
                                                # blank line
Intergenic7+e3u                                 # first delimiter == "+"
intron9(NM_201628, intron 1 of 14)              # first delimiter == "("
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
    { split($0,arr,"[^[:alnum:]]")              # split line using all non-alphanumerics as delimiters
      if ( arr[1] != "" )                       # if not a blank line ...
         count[tolower(arr[1])]++               # lowecase/count the first field
    }
END { for (i in count)                          # loop through list of words
      printf "%s count : %s\n", i, count[i]
    }
' list.dat

# or as a one-liner (sans comments)

awk '{split($0,arr,"[^[:alnum:]]"); if (arr[1] != "") count[tolower(arr[1])]++} END {for (i in count) printf "%s count : %s\n", i, count[i]}' list.dat
```

This generates:

```
intergenic7 count : 1
intron9 count : 1
intron count : 3
intergenic count : 4
promoter count : 1
```

**NOTES:**

- we're using `tolower()` to facilitate case-insensitive comparison so all output is lowercase
- OP hasn't stipulated how the output is to be used so this solution could be further modified to take into consideration display order, saving to a file, saving to an associative array, etc